Count number of cells within an AOI using terra::extract
I am using terra::extract function to extract various statistics from imagery using a grid. So each grid cell contains X number of pixels, since any pixel intersecting the grid cell can be included, I need to know how many cells are contained within each calculation. Basically I am trying to figure out which function I can use for the argument fun which will return the count of the objects used for the statistical calculations.
ZM <- terra::extract(imagery, GRID, fun= ?)
ZM <- terra::extract(imagery, GRID, fun= n)
ZM <- terra::extract(imagery, GRID, fun= count)

You should be able to get the number of cells intersecting with a vector feature by passing ncell to the fun argument (assuming your GRID is a SpatVector object):
library(terra)
#> terra 1.7.78

# get some data
r <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package = "terra") |> rast()

v <- system.file("ex/lux.shp", package = "terra") |> vect()

# get number of cells intersecting your vector feature
extract(r, v[1, ], fun = ncell)
#>   ID elevation
#> 1  1       567

# check if result aligns with another approach
extract(r, v[1, ]) |> dim()
#> [1] 567   2

Using this data, the number of 567 cells can be reproduced and seems to be valid.
Note: With exact = TRUE, ncell() will return a different number of course.

Happy to help! Feel free to accept my answer to get your question 'closed' if this solved your issue, otherwise it will appear as unanswered to others.
